# Почему не работает "кнопка" Одноклассников?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Установил на сайт кнопки соц.сетей, при попытке поставить "класс" в Одноклассниках, открывается окно с надписью - " Нет доступа к ресурсу
Попробуйте позже".

Comment: Скорее всего, вы хотите поделиться страницей, доступа к которой нет у бота одноклассников.

Comment: Адрес, которым вы делитесь, доступен из внешней сети?

Comment: Да, адрес доступен. Кроме того, работают все кнопки, кроме одноклассников.

Comment: У вас есть возможность указать ссылку на страницу, на которой размещены кнопки?

Comment: http://pirgoroj.ru/pasxa-s-kuragoj/html

Comment: Фейсбук тоже не может достучаться до сайта – можно заметить, что ни картинка, ни описание не подгружаются. Также можно воспользоваться отладчиком, он показывает код ответа 503. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpirgoroj.ru%2Fpasxa-s-kuragoj

Comment: Так что в итоге делать то? Просто я ещё "чайник" в этой теме, только начинаю - это мой первый сайт. Очень сложно разобраться. Перерыл массу материала, а результата пока нет.